# Difference between join and where

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Trying to improve a query with multiple join (Query taking 22s :-/).

In the first I see a linq query with many from and where restriction... When I saw the genreated SQL I see many nested 'FROM ( SELECT FROM (SELECT'...

I changed that code with JOIN like that :

```
var groupPlans = (from client in Context.PERINSURANCECLIENT
    join person in Context.PERLEGALSTRUCTURE on client.MYIDENTITY_ID equals person.ID
    join groupAgreement in Context.GROUPAGREEMENT on client.ID equals groupAgreement.SUBSCRIBER_ID
    join groupPlan in Context.CNTPOLICY on groupAgreement.ID equals groupPlan.GROUPAGREEMENT_ID
    join product in Context.PROPRODUCT on groupPlan.MYPRODUCT_ID equals product.ID
    join pdv in Context.PERINSURANCEPARTNER on groupPlan.MYPOINTVENTE_ID equals pdv.ID

    where client.NSID == clientNSID
    && client.MYIDENTITY_NSID == legalNSID
    && groupAgreement.SUBSCRIBER_NSID == client.NSID
    && groupPlan.GROUPAGREEMENT_NSID == groupAgreement.NSID
    && groupPlan.NSID == NSIDgroupPlan
    && groupAgreement.NSID == NSIDGroupAgreement
        && groupPlan.MYPOINTVENTE_ID == pdv.ID

    && pdv.NSID == pdvNSID
    && groupPlan.MYGLOBALPOLICY_ID != 0 &&
    groupPlan.MYGLOBALPOLICY_NSID != 0 &&
    groupPlan.MYNEXTENDORSEMENT_ID == 0 &&
    (groupPlan.NATURE == 0 || groupPlan.NATURE == 1 || groupPlan.NATURE == 4 || groupPlan.NATURE == 2) &&
    (groupPlan.STATUS == 0 || groupPlan.STATUS == 1 || groupPlan.STATUS == 2 || groupPlan.STATUS == 3) &&
    groupPlan.MYPRODUCT_NSID == product.NSID &&
    groupPlan.MYPRODUCT_VERSION == -product.VERSION &&
    groupPlan.H_ISKILLED == 0
    &&
    product.NSID == productNSID
    orderby groupPlan.REFERENCE descending
    select new
    {
        LineOfBusiness = product.GSLINEOFBUSINESS,
        Produit = product.NAME,
        ProduitId = product.ID,
        Nature = groupPlan.NATURE,
        Etat = groupPlan.STATUS,
        EndorsmentNumber = groupPlan.ENDORSEMENTNUMBER,
        AssureName = person.NAME,
        Reference = groupPlan.REFERENCE,
        Id = groupAgreement.ID,
        PolicyNSID = groupPlan.NSID,
        NomPDV = pdv.NAME,
        CodePDV = pdv.CODEPOINTVENTE,
        PDVId = pdv.ID,
        IdClient = client.ID,
        IdIdentity = person.ID,
        Isreversed = groupPlan.ISREVERSED,
        PreviousEndorsemntID = groupPlan.MYPREVIOUSENDORSEMENT_ID,
        DateCreation = groupAgreement.CREATIONDATE,
        ValidityDate = groupPlan.DATEFINVALIDITEDEVIS,
        ReferenceAgreement = groupAgreement.REFERENCE,
        CodeSiret = person.SIRETNO,
        EffectiveDate = groupPlan.EFFECTIVEDATE,
    });
```

Conclusion : same issue here with no performance improving...

If you have any idea how can I improve this query or some explication about JOIN vs FROM WHERE...

Here the sql generated (captured with Interllitrace)

```
SELECT TOP (100) 
[Project1].[NSID] AS [NSID], 
[Project1].[GSLINEOFBUSINESS] AS [GSLINEOFBUSINESS], 
[Project1].[NAME1] AS [NAME], 
[Project1].[ID3] AS [ID], 
[Project1].[NATURE] AS [NATURE], 
[Project1].[STATUS] AS [STATUS], 
[Project1].[ENDORSEMENTNUMBER] AS [ENDORSEMENTNUMBER], 
[Project1].[NAME] AS [NAME1], 
[Project1].[REFERENCE1] AS [REFERENCE], 
[Project1].[ID2] AS [ID1], 
[Project1].[NAME2] AS [NAME2], 
[Project1].[CODEPOINTVENTE] AS [CODEPOINTVENTE], 
[Project1].[ID4] AS [ID2], 
[Project1].[ID] AS [ID3], 
[Project1].[ID1] AS [ID4], 
[Project1].[ISREVERSED] AS [ISREVERSED], 
[Project1].[MYPREVIOUSENDORSEMENT_ID] AS [MYPREVIOUSENDORSEMENT_ID], 
[Project1].[CREATIONDATE] AS [CREATIONDATE], 
[Project1].[DATEFINVALIDITEDEVIS] AS [DATEFINVALIDITEDEVIS], 
[Project1].[REFERENCE] AS [REFERENCE1], 
[Project1].[SIRETNO] AS [SIRETNO], 
[Project1].[EFFECTIVEDATE] AS [EFFECTIVEDATE]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Filter1].[ID1] AS [ID], 
    [Filter1].[ID2] AS [ID1], 
    [Filter1].[NAME1] AS [NAME], 
    [Filter1].[SIRETNO] AS [SIRETNO], 
    [Filter1].[ID3] AS [ID2], 
    [Filter1].[REFERENCE1] AS [REFERENCE], 
    [Filter1].[CREATIONDATE1] AS [CREATIONDATE], 
    [Filter1].[NSID1] AS [NSID], 
    [Filter1].[REFERENCE2] AS [REFERENCE1], 
    [Filter1].[ENDORSEMENTNUMBER] AS [ENDORSEMENTNUMBER], 
    [Filter1].[NATURE] AS [NATURE], 
    [Filter1].[STATUS1] AS [STATUS], 
    [Filter1].[ISREVERSED] AS [ISREVERSED], 
    [Filter1].[EFFECTIVEDATE1] AS [EFFECTIVEDATE], 
    [Filter1].[MYPREVIOUSENDORSEMENT_ID] AS [MYPREVIOUSENDORSEMENT_ID], 
    [Filter1].[DATEFINVALIDITEDEVIS] AS [DATEFINVALIDITEDEVIS], 
    [Filter1].[ID4] AS [ID3], 
    [Filter1].[NAME2] AS [NAME1], 
    [Filter1].[GSLINEOFBUSINESS] AS [GSLINEOFBUSINESS], 
    [Extent6].[ID] AS [ID4], 
    [Extent6].[NAME] AS [NAME2], 
    [Extent6].[CODEPOINTVENTE] AS [CODEPOINTVENTE]
    FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[NSID] AS [NSID2], [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID1], [Extent1].[MYIDENTITY_NSID] AS [MYIDENTITY_NSID], [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID2], [Extent2].[NAME] AS [NAME1], [Extent2].[SIRETNO] AS [SIRETNO], [Extent3].[NSID] AS [NSID3], [Extent3].[ID] AS [ID3], [Extent3].[REFERENCE] AS [REFERENCE1], [Extent3].[CREATIONDATE] AS [CREATIONDATE1], [Extent4].[NSID] AS [NSID1], [Extent4].[REFERENCE] AS [REFERENCE2], [Extent4].[ENDORSEMENTNUMBER] AS [ENDORSEMENTNUMBER], [Extent4].[NATURE] AS [NATURE], [Extent4].[STATUS] AS [STATUS1], [Extent4].[ISREVERSED] AS [ISREVERSED], [Extent4].[EFFECTIVEDATE] AS [EFFECTIVEDATE1], [Extent4].[MYPREVIOUSENDORSEMENT_ID] AS [MYPREVIOUSENDORSEMENT_ID], [Extent4].[DATEFINVALIDITEDEVIS] AS [DATEFINVALIDITEDEVIS], [Extent4].[MYPOINTVENTE_ID] AS [MYPOINTVENTE_ID], [Extent5].[NSID] AS [NSID4], [Extent5].[ID] AS [ID4], [Extent5].[NAME] AS [NAME2], [Extent5].[GSLINEOFBUSINESS] AS [GSLINEOFBUSINESS]
        FROM     [dbo].[PERINSURANCECLIENT] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[PERLEGALSTRUCTURE] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[MYIDENTITY_ID] = [Extent2].[ID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[GROUPAGREEMENT] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent1].[ID] = [Extent3].[SUBSCRIBER_ID]) AND ([Extent3].[SUBSCRIBER_NSID] = [Extent1].[NSID])
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[CNTPOLICY] AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent3].[ID] = [Extent4].[GROUPAGREEMENT_ID]) AND ([Extent4].[GROUPAGREEMENT_NSID] = [Extent3].[NSID])
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[PROPRODUCT] AS [Extent5] ON ([Extent4].[MYPRODUCT_ID] = [Extent5].[ID]) AND ([Extent4].[MYPRODUCT_NSID] = [Extent5].[NSID])
        WHERE (cast(0 as decimal(18)) <> [Extent4].[MYGLOBALPOLICY_ID]) AND (0 <> [Extent4].[MYGLOBALPOLICY_NSID]) AND (cast(0 as decimal(18)) = [Extent4].[MYNEXTENDORSEMENT_ID]) AND ((0 =  CAST( [Extent4].[NATURE] AS int)) OR (1 =  CAST( [Extent4].[NATURE] AS int)) OR (4 =  CAST( [Extent4].[NATURE] AS int)) OR (2 =  CAST( [Extent4].[NATURE] AS int))) AND ((0 =  CAST( [Extent4].[STATUS] AS int)) OR (1 =  CAST( [Extent4].[STATUS] AS int)) OR (2 =  CAST( [Extent4].[STATUS] AS int)) OR (3 =  CAST( [Extent4].[STATUS] AS int))) AND (0 = [Extent4].[H_ISKILLED]) AND ([Extent4].[MYPRODUCT_VERSION] = ( -([Extent5].[VERSION]))) ) AS [Filter1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PERINSURANCEPARTNER] AS [Extent6] ON [Filter1].[MYPOINTVENTE"
```

**[EDIT]**

After some investigation in Database, I see that there are too many indexes (6000 indexes of 1000 tables)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to rewrite the linq query to make it faster but have you looked at the execution plan? There might be an index missing that can speed up the query with very little effort.

Comment: Start with improving the formatting.  No one wants to scroll to the right.  And the last TSQL is not complete - only half an ON.  Did you test moving the where conditions up into the join?  We don't have your data to test with.

Comment: @Blamm sorry for that, yes I tried moving the where conditions up into the join and I saw no difference

Comment: @acfrancis yes I have that in the pipe, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`SelectMany` followed by `Where` is terrible in LINQ to objects as it has no means of optimizing the code.  In SQL a from-from/where has ample opportunity to be optimized by the DB before it's actually run, so it's not really that much of a problem.  Since this transformation was previously being done by the DB anyway, you didn't see much improvement, as I would have expected.

While joins are inherently a lot faster than cross products, they're still not the cheapest operations around.  It's entirely possible that just joining all of the data that you have (depending on the amount of data in all of the tables) is just that much, and takes that much time to execute even with sensible implementations.